# test case to fail fwrite()

Tags: c, linux, fwrite

I am trying to test fwrite. I am trying to write a usecase in which fwrite fails. Here is waht i tried.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main()
{
        char arr[6] = "manty";
        int ret;
        FILE *fp;
        printf("Before fwrite - errno - %d\n", errno);
        // fp = fopen("fwrite_test.txt", "w+");
        ret = fwrite(arr, sizeof(arr) + 2, 1, fp);
        printf ("ret - %d errno - %d ferror - %d\n", ret, errno, ferror(fp));
        return 0;
}
```

By wantedly commenting fopen() I thought fwrite will return an error. But it gives a segmentation fault.

How cani test fwrite()?

Comment: It looks like testcases for the rightness of `fwrite()` is much easy to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fwrite(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwrite.3.html) may sometimes call the [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) syscall, but not always, since [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) is buffered (see [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html) for more). And `fwrite` will fail if `write` is failing.

You could limit the file size [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) with `RLIMIT_FSIZE` (and install or ignore a `SIGXFSZ` [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) handler). In particular by using the `ulimit` builtin of `bash` shell. Then you could `fwrite` a big enough data buffer (larger than the limit). You could also set quotas on a file system (see [quotactl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/quotactl.2.html), [quotaon(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/quotaon.8.html) etc...) then write over quota limits. At last, you could write in a small filesystem above its capacities (see *Example* section of [losetup(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/losetup.8.html) to make a tiny filesystem...). In all these cases `write` will fail (so `fwrite` too).

Answer (score 3):

Your uninitialized variable `fp` here results in [undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior-in-c) [behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value), which in your case is leading to a crash since your are trying to write on memory that is outside your process scope.

In order to write test cases for `fwrite` you will need to avoid situations that can cause undefined behavior, such as this one and some listed by [leeduhem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22214481/1670308) , and then pass your parameters as you wish to test them.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is much easy to write testcases for the rightnecss of `fwrite()` instead of for the falures of it, because many conditions that may cause `fwrite()` to fail, such as uninitialized input buffer, write more data than the input buffer actually has, uninitialized file stream, will lead to undefined behaviors according to C standard.

So under these conditions, it is hard to say whether you are testing `fwrite()` or are exploring the actual behaviors of these undefined behaviors in your specific testing circumstance.